# Downloading Binary File from OneDrive API Using Node/Axios

Tags: node.js, axios, onedrive

I am using the *One Drive API* to grab a file with a node application using the axios library.

I am simply trying to save the file to the local machine (node is running locally).

I use the One Drive API to get the download document link, which does not require authentication (with https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/drives/[location]/items/[id]).

Then I make this call with the download document link:

`response = await axios.get(url);`

I receive a JSON response, which includes, among other things, the content-type, content-length, content-disposition and a data element which is the contents of the file.

When I display the JSON response to the console, the data portion looks like this:

`data: 'PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u...'`

If the document is simply text, I can save it easily using:

`fs.writeFileSync([path], response.data);`

But if the file is binary, like a `docx` file, I cannot figure out how to write it properly. Every time I try it seems to have the wrong encoding.  I tried different encodings.

How do I save the file properly based on the type of file retrieved.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using an `encoding` option of [`fs.writeFileSync`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest-v12.x/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options) of explicitly null, signifying the data is binary?

```
fs.writeFileSync([path], response.data, {
  encoding: null
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not work.  The original doc is 17KB and the downloaded one is 29KB. It won't open in Word.

When I display the JSON response to the console, the data portion looks like this:   data: 'PK\u0003\u0004\u0014\u0000\u0006\u0000\b\u0000\u0000\u0000!\u...'